# How to dispatch actions every ten seconds and stop them on another action?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

In my application I have actions: 'GET_USER', 'GET_DOCS'.

I want to dispatch those actions every ten seconds using effects.

for example, in some component I dispatch an action: `startAutoDispatch`, the effects catch this action and start dispach others actions every ten seconds.

Something like this effect:

```
createEffects(() => this.actions$.pipe(
 ofType('startAutoDispatch')
 switchMap(() => ([
  { type: 'GET_USER', payload: null },
  { type: 'GET_DOCS', payload: null }
 ])
```

This is not works. and I don't have the timer to dispatch those actions again and again.

Also I want if the action `stopAutoDispatch` dispatch then stop the timer.

How can I solve this issue in rxjs way/ngrx way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
createEffects(() =>
  this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType('startAutoDispatch'),
    switchMap(() =>
      timer(0, 10 * 1000).pipe(
        mergeMap(() =>
          from([
            { type: 'GET_USER', payload: null },
            { type: 'GET_DOCS', payload: null },
          ])
        ),
        takeUntil(this.actions$.pipe(ofType('stopAutoDispatch')))
      )
    )
  )
);
```

- listen for the start
- use `timer` to repeatedly emit the 2 actions you want
- stop dispatching those actions if the `stopAutoDispatch` is dispatched (until `startAutoDispatch` is dispatched again)